# Chrome Extention chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab return undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Trying to get screenshot of opened tab on browser through a chrome extention. Using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab to achieve this.

This is the code on background script-

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request, sender);
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(sender.tab.windowId, {}, function (dataUrl) {
    console.log('inside capture');
    sendResponse({
      imgSrc: dataUrl
    });
    console.log(dataUrl);  // prints undefined
  });

  return true;
});
```

code on content script:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      {
        msg: 'capture'
      },
      function (response) {
        console.log(response.dataUrl);  // prints undefined
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

manifest code:

```
    "manifest_version": 3,
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "alarms",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

Comment: The "<all_urls>" permission should be in the "host_permissions" field of manifest.json, not in the "permissions" field. Then the line `console.log(dataUrl);` in the background script will no longer print `undefined`.

Comment: In the content script, the line `console.log(response.dataUrl);` should be `console.log(response.imgSrc);`

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Appreciate you help!